# Would a lack of sticky sessions cause a session to be terminated and user authentication to be reset?

Tags: kubernetes

If we had multiple pods but no sticky sessions, would an additional request cause the request to shift pod and thus reset the authentication for a user?

My understanding of sessions in kubernetes is that without sticky sessions, requests are handled in a 'round robin' way whereby a setup with 2 pods would handle requests pod 1 pod 2 1 2 etc. Could this potentially cause authentication to be reset?

Thanks

Comment: It depends entirely on how your application handles authentication, but the short answer is "yes". Lack of sticky sessions could lead to authentication problems.